# top results + remaining results, with %

Tags: mdx, adventureworks

I'm trying to create a MDX query to show the top 10 results + an aggregation of all other results that are part of the 10 first. So far so good. But I also want to show the percentage of each result. This is what I have so far. You can try in Adventure Works:

```
WITH
SET [TCat] AS TopCount([Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory],10,[Measures].[Sales Amount])
MEMBER [Product].[Subcategory].[Other] AS Aggregate([Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory] - TCat)
MEMBER [Measures].[Percent] AS [Measures].[Sales Amount] / ([Measures].[Sales Amount],[Product].[Subcategory].CurrentMember.Parent),format_string='0.00%'

SELECT { [Measures].[Sales Amount], [Measures].[Percent] } ON COLUMNS,
TCat + [Other] ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Everything works fine, except for the % of [Other].
Can anybody help me to fix this final issue?

Answer (score 0):

The Member [Product].[Subcategory].CurrentMember.Parent isn't Parent from [Other] Member.

Try this solution:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Product].[Subcategory].[Parent] AS Aggregate([Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory])
SET [TCat] AS TopCount([Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory],10,[Measures].[Sales Amount])
MEMBER [Product].[Subcategory].[Other] AS Aggregate([Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory] - TCat)
MEMBER [Measures].[Percent] AS [Measures].[Sales Amount] / ([Measures].[Sales Amount], [Product].[Subcategory].[Parent]),format_string='0.00%'

SELECT { [Measures].[Sales Amount], [Measures].[Percent] } ON COLUMNS,
TCat + [Other] ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
```